# How do I pull a branch from origin to local while working with git-worktree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

What I am used to in the main worktree land:

- I want to work on my co-workers branch as they are on holiday

on branch `main`, I run `git pull origin/main`, this fast forwards and pulls all refs down to my local.
My co-worker's branch is `newFeature`, so I run `git checkout newFeature` and I am on that branch!

How do I do the same when working with a bare repo and git worktrees?
I cannot figure out how to checkout `newFeature` locally, such that I have a folder right beside my `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need [multiple working directories with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309), you can:

- clone your bare repository
- from within that cloned repo folder, type:

  ```
  git worktree add -b newFeature ../newFeature origin/newFeature
  ```

That will create a `newFeature` for that branch, beside your local repo folder.

---

The [OP Saiborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528969/saiborg) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179162/how-do-i-pull-a-branch-from-origin-to-local-while-working-with-git-worktree/75179491?noredirect=1#comment132682046_75179491):

> In order for me to do what I wanted, I just had to do this:
>
> ```
> git worktree add -b feature/newFeature newFeature origin/feature/newFeature
> ```
>
> which worked as expected.

Comment: I am in the bare repo (`.bare`, `main` folders I can see when I run `ls -a`). Are you suggesting I run this in this context? If I am not wrong, wouldn't this create a folder adjacent to the bare repo and not in the bare repo like how `main` is? Is there a way to do this such that, `main`, `newFeature` are at the same level as such, `myCloneBareRepo/main`, `myCloneBareRepo/newFeature`?

Comment: @SaiBorg I was suggesting that you clone first the bare repository, then execute the git worktree command in the cloned repository.

Comment: That is what I have done! Also comment from last night just after maintenance:
paste in so as it is down for maint
I think I have figured it out! In order for me to do what I wanted, I just had to do this: `git worktree add -b feature/newFeature newFeature origin/feature/newFeature` which worked as expected. @VonC

Comment: @SaiBorg Well done, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.